# Report Viewer Control & ASPX Login Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, report

I have been suffering with login issues on my aspx webforms application intermittently and the only way to resolve the issue is to Restart the App Pool (IIS7). The symptoms were.. getting to the login page, If incorrect details were entered it says incorrect details. If correct details are entered it will just loop back to the login page.

I have found what causes the issue but not sure how to fix...
I have a report viewer control in the members area which is in remote mode connecting to the report server. This uses IReportServerCredentials with credentials stored in my Web.Config. When a report is run it connects fine and displays fine. When I close the browser and open again it wont allow me to login to the members area. I have to restart the app pool to get logged in.

It creates 2 cookies...

ASPNET.Application - On Members Area Login (Standard ASP Login System)

ASP.NET_SessionId - When Running The Report (Guess this has report server credentials)

Any ideas what's causing this and why I have to restart the App Pool every time I run a report?